# I have added the GUI code in my three js file but it's not working not raising any error either

Tags: javascript, user-interface, three.js

I added the gui code in the in my code as it was shown in the github repo of **mrdoob**. It is not raising any error and it is not showing up in the page, i'm new to three js.

```
    import * as THREE from './js/three.module.js';
    import { GUI } from './js/dat.gui.module.js';
    import { OrbitControls } from './js/OrbitControls.js';
    import Stats from './js/stats.module.js';
    import {
      createPlaneLambertMaterial,
      createCubeLambertMaterial,
      createSphereLambertMaterial,
    } from './basics-geometry.js';
    import { createSpotlight } from './light.js';
    import axesHelper from './helper.js';
    
    function init() {
      var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    
      const fov = 45; // AKA Field of View
      const aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
      const near = 0.1; // the near clipping plane
      const far = 1000;
      var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
      camera.position.x = -30;
      camera.position.y = 40;
      camera.position.z = 30;
      camera.lookAt(scene.position);
    
      var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
      renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color(0xeeeeee, 1.0));
      renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
      renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    
      var controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    
      // x - red , y - green, z - blue axis lines
      scene.add(axesHelper(20));
    
      // Shape Geometry
      const plane = createPlaneLambertMaterial({ receiveShadow: true });
      scene.add(plane);
      const cube = createCubeLambertMaterial({ castShadow: true });
      scene.add(cube);
      const sphere = createSphereLambertMaterial({ castShadow: true });
      scene.add(sphere);
    
      // Light
      createSpotlight({ scene: scene, x: -40, y: 60, z: -10, castShadow: true });
    
      controls.enableDamping = true;
      //   controls.autoRotate = true;
      controls.update();
    
      var stats = new Stats();
      stats.showPanel(0); // 0: fps, 1: ms, 2: mb, 3+: custom
      document.body.appendChild(stats.dom);
    
      var helper = new THREE.GridHelper(2000, 100);
      helper.position.y = -199;
      helper.material.opacity = 0.25;
      helper.material.transparent = true;
      scene.add(helper);
    
      let step = 0;
      let rSpeed = 0;
    
      // GUI
      var params = new function () {
        this.rotationSpeed = 0.02;
        this.bouncingSpeed = 0.03;
      };
    
      var gui = new GUI();
      gui.add(params, 'rotationSpeed', 0, 0.5);
      gui.add(params, 'bouncingSpeed', 0, 0.5);
      gui.open();
    
      function render() {
        stats.update();
        controls.update();
    
        step += params.bouncingSpeed;
        rSpeed = params.rotationSpeed;
    
        cube.rotation.x += rSpeed;
        cube.rotation.y += rSpeed;
        cube.rotation.z += rSpeed;
    
        sphere.position.x = 20 + 10 * Math.cos(step);
        sphere.position.y = 2 + 10 * Math.abs(Math.sin(step));
    
        requestAnimationFrame(render);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
      }
    
      render();
      document.getElementById('c').appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    }
    window.onload = init;
```

[Github repo](https://github.com/ChiragKushwaha/Three-JS/blob/master/main.js) for the whole code

Answer (score 0):

you have to add the gui domElement to the webpage

```
 document.getElementById('gui').appendChild(gui.domElement);
```